# Pass Entity object as parameter to controller function in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller, cakephp-3.0

I have a project of CakePHP 3.1 and I'm looking for a way to pass as parameter an Entity object and an array to a controller using the FormHelper postLink.

What I have already tried:

```
echo $this->Form->postLink(
                __('Unlink'),
                ['action' => 'unlink', $entity, $array],
                ['confirm' => __('Are you sure to unlink {0}?', $array['name'])]);
```

My controller:

```
public function unlink($entity,$array)
{
    $theTable = TableRegistry::get('tableName');
    $theTable->Model->unlink($entity, $array);
    return $this->redirect($this->referer());
}
```

This is displaying a pretty known error:

> rawurlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string

But I haven't find any post that fits my needs, I guess it is because I need to pass an object instead of basic types.

Any help or better alternative is appreciated.

Comment: maybe you could send the id of the entity and get it in your controller via `$this->EntityName->get($id);`

Comment: @B.Kevin That would mean two more queries to the db when I already have the data. I've already thought that but I think it is not the best option, but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Unless you need to handle 10.000 unlink requests per second, these two queries for the entities are really nothing to be concerned about. Not to mention that passing around serialized objects when it's not technically required, generally doesn't sound like an overly good idea.

Comment: Also, why are you using postLink() when the unlink() method in the controller doesn't even check for the HTTP verb?

Comment: @ndm Ok thank you, I am always a bit concern about the performance... if that's the case only passing the ids of the entity and the element which is going to be unlinked should be enough... I just feel weird to query information that I already have. Maybe I'm not understanding what `get()` does...

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass only the entity id as parameter (not the entity) and do the job inside unlink action:

```
echo $this->Form->postLink(
            __('Unlink'),
            ['action' => 'unlink', $entity->id, $array],
            ['confirm' => __('Are you sure to unlink {0}?', $array['name'])]);
```

and inside unlink:

```
public function unlink($id = null ,$array = [])
{
    if (is_null($id)) {
        // an error flash message can be set here
        return $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }       
    $theTable = TableRegistry::get('tableName');
    $theEntity = $theTable->get($id);
    $theTable->unlink($theEntity, $array);
    return $this->redirect($this->referer());       
}
```